# How do I add linked custom PHP page to plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am attempting to build my first plugin.

I have a form that collects the infon necessary to create a post. Before I allow the post to go into the Database I need to force the user to accept my TOS.

I have a checkbox and a link. The link will go to the TOS page (my custom PHP page) and once the user accepts the TOS the user can come back to the FORM which is populated with their data and the checkbox is checked.

The user can also just check the box and submit their post.

My question is how do I wrap my TOS page so that it matches the existing website. I want my PHP page to be wrapped to use whatever theme the user has selected for their website. In addition I want to come back to the form with it wrapped in the users theme just like it was originally.

I open my form using a hook so all is good up to there.

I want to understand how to do this the right way not the cheap and easy way.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

```
<a href="test.php">To TOS</a>

<?PHP
    echo '<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>Terms Of Service</br>1. TOS 1</br>2. TOS 2<BODY></HTML>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i read about fake pages. http://betterwp.net/98-wordpress-create-fake-pages/ that might be your answer.

Comment: My challenge is not pushing the data around or getting it into the database. My issue is wrapping the TOS page in the theme, then coming back to my form page and having it wrapped in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to learn the basics of Wordpress because after you create your plugin, it will work with most themes unless you create the plugin targeting specific themes with specific classes or id's.

You can however add libraries to your plugin so it can use them for specific tasks. You will probably need to build a plugin for what you are asking for. But if you are good with PHP, you wont have an issue.

I suggest starting at Wordpress Codex for reference to the Plugin API:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: My original plugin page is started through a hook and is wrapped in the exsting theme fine. My issue is, when I link from that form and go to the PHP page that shows the TOS, how to I properly wrap that page in the existing theme. I know I can pull in the header footer and sidebar manually depending on a specific theme but I want to be sure I match the current theme whatever that may be.

Comment: Then you obviously didn't read the documentation properly on the Plugin API, I suggest you read it carefully because we can't write the code for you if you haven't even tried to! If you did, post the code so we can see what the issue is!

Comment: My apologies if something is not sinking in for me. I'll do some more research. Thanks very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to do it. The way I do it is as below

1. Create Shortcode for your form

   add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'my_shortcode_handler' );
2. Create function my_shortcode_handler

   function my_shortcode_handler( $atts, $content = null ) {
      include ('myhtmlform.php');
   }
3. Create myhtmlform.php, insert your logic.
4. Call "[myshortcode]" in any page you want your form in

P.S.
 Insert all this code in your plugin main file.

Regards

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding or I'm not explaining correctly. I have a shortcode that starts my original form. Now I need to link from that form over to my TOS. I can't expect my wordpress admins to create two pages with two different shortcodes, one for the original form and another for the TOS correct?

Comment: just create the link. what is the problem ?

Comment: lol, I did. Check it out, shawnweb.com/test login with testuser/1LjCGk4Ss9Qe . Choose "add a poem". Go go the bottom of the form and click the link("test link"). See, no header or footer or sidebar.

Comment: file_get_content(), and return the result of the file. you are echoing it.

Comment: What page will file_get_contents() go on? And what file am I grabbing? I'm echoing out the HTML on my php page just as an example of a page that I want to wrap in Wordpress. In essence this is my TOS page.

Comment: show your code. what your are actually doing. So I can help better.

Comment: I updated my original question. The first is a link to my php page, then the code for a simple php page that spits out the TOS.

Comment: create a simple wordpress page programmitically and link it to your anchor 

Code

global $user_ID;

$page['post_type']    = 'page';
$page['post_content'] = 'Put your page content here';
$page['post_parent']  = 0;
$page['post_author']  = $user_ID;
$page['post_status']  = 'publish';
$page['post_title']   = 'Your Page Title';
$page = apply_filters('yourplugin_add_new_page', $page, 'teams');
$pageid = wp_insert_post ($page);
if ($pageid == 0) { /* Add Page Failed */ }

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Martaza. I'll not be able to try this out until later today most likely. I'll report back then on how it goes. Until then, thanks a million.

Comment: No Problem. do comment here so I can help further. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The best (and most complicated way) is to add a rewrite rule and rewrite tag:

Add a tag like this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

And then a rewrite rule:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

You'll then have a pointer to something like YOURDOMAIN.com/YOUR-URL,
with the proper variables in the global WP Query to point to a template-file,
which you can do with the action 'template_redirect'

So:

```
//add the rewrite tag to the WP Query (called on the init action, or earlier)
add_rewrite_tag('%terms-of-service%','([^&]+)');

//add a rewrite rule: (init or earlier)
add_rewrite_rule('^terms-of-service/?','index.php?tos=true','top');

//And then add an action on 'template_redirect':
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'tos_query' );

function tos_query(){

   global $wp_query;

   if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['terms-of-service'] ) ){

      locate_template( --YOUR URL-- )

   }

}
```

Bear in mind that the rewrite api of WordPress is an annoying minefield, you're going to need to use

```
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Before it all works, probably...

This plugin has a great way of handeling a redirect: http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-portfolio/ (although it's for a post-type, not a function )

Comment: Thanks LucP I'll read up on this. I really appreciate your help.